# Check-in User & Check-in Comments

Tags: powershell, build-automation

I have created a build definition in TFS 2012 that uses a PowerShell script. In this script, I would like to retrieve the Check-in User and the Check-in Comments, after the code has check-in.

Is there such a macro that can be used during the build process?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow sequence right outside the `Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items`  parallel activity defines a variable called `associatedChangesets` which is an IList.  Try passing that into your script.  I've only passed simple string variables into my scripts e.g.:

```
"-NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command ""& {" + SourcesDirectory + "\Build\MakeSdkZip.ps1 " + SourcesDirectory + " " + SdkDbgZipPath + " -TeamBuild -IncludeSource}"""
```

This is the Arguments value for one of my PowerShell invocations.  Note that SourcesDirectory and SdkDbgZipPath are workflow defined variables.  Also keep in mind that there can be multiple checkins per build (hence the collection of changesets).